# How do I sanitize all my string inputs using Entity Framework Core and Npgsql?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, npgsql

So, here is the issue: the system can sometimes create in some of the strings the null character (\0). This is by design and is working properly. The issue is that when I want to store this data in the DAL I need to first get rid of all the null characters (PostgreSQL does not support the null character). In theory, I can go all over each of the inputs and manually sanitize it, but this can be a very long and painful process. I am wondering, is there a fast and easy way to just sanitize all of those strings using the Entity Framework Core itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the [value converters feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions).

Comment: No, this is a solution that is per entity. I am looking for a solution that is for all strings that go into the DAL

Comment: In general EF isn&#39;t responsible for your DAL. However, you can quite easily write code that finds all string properties on your entities and sets value converters on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bulk-configuration as listed in this example.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#bulk-configuring-a-value-converter